# Installing Polymer firebase-collection

Tags: firebase, polymer

I can't seem to figure out how to get Polymer's `<firebase-collection>` element into my project. I have installed many of the paper and iron elements but I don't have the firebase ones in my bower-components, I don't see it in the Bower registry and I can't find the right repo in Github. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
bower install --save polymer/firebase-element
```

However this gives dependency errors with polymer 1.0.

https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/issues/38

Comment: Just to add to this. You can also go [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-collection), and add the `firebase-collection` to your collection and download either the `bower.json` file or a zip file containing the code.

Comment: I am using 1.0 but I didn't think about adding it to my collection and downloading it since I usually just pull it in with bower. One other note: when you go to download your collection it also give you the bower install string `bower install --save GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element#^1.0.0`.